# Laravel filter models by count of related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, eloquent, relationship

I have a list of Groups with Users. Groups has a property `maximum_users`. Users can register in a Group only if they have a free place (*If count of registered users in that Group does not exceed `maximum_users` property of that Group*).

- How can I select only Groups with free places where Users can register?
- I need to paginate the results.

I can filter groups after selecting them with this condition:

```
$group->maximum_users >= $group->users()->count()
```

but in this case pagination doesn't work.

Table structure:

```
groups
    id - integer
    maximum_users - integer

users
    id - integer
    group_id - integer
```

Models:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}


class User extends Model
{
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your controller call/function, how are you trying to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I select only Groups with free places where Users can register?
>   I need to paginate the results.

i would strongly recommend to use a pivot table, unless user can only be in one group, with pivot table something like this should work:

```php
Group::whereRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM groups_users 
                  WHERE group_id = group.id) < group.maximum_users')
    ->paginate(15);
```

**With your current structure**

```php
Group::whereRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM users 
                  WHERE group_id = groups.id) < groups.maximum_users')
    ->paginate(15);
```